# Can't preview SwiftUI Canvas with RealityKit scene

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I only create a new property of RealityKit.
Xcode won't be able to preview the SwiftUI canvas.
But it can build successfully.

1. I create the App by Xcode.
2. Choose **Augmented Reality App** and set User **Interface to SwiftUI**.
3. The project can work normally.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("123")
            ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

        // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()

        // Add the box anchor to the scene
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)

        return arView

    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}

}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

4. I only create a new property of RealityKit in makeUIView function.

```swift
let test: AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment = .horizontal
```

5. The project cannot preview canvas and appear the error

   > 'Alignment' is not a member type of 'AnchoringComponent.Target'

[image]

6. The project still can compile successful.
   [image]

I am so confused what I met.
Has anyone meet the same issue?

Comment: My guess is that RealityKit is not available on the canvas because it's too heavy, so it can't be imported, that's why you see that error. Also, don't put your code as images, paste it as text, that way it can be copied and searched.

Comment: But if I create a new property at another files, it cannot build successful too. okay! I will change code to text. thanks

Comment: If I don't add the property, It will can preview, although it only show the white canvas, but I can make other layout on this SwiftUI file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to fix several issues**:

> 1. You can't use `anchoring component` **in iOS Simulator** or in **SwiftUI Canvas Preview**, because it can only be used for pinning a virtual content to the real world surfaces. **So no simulator for AR apps**.

RealityKit Anchors are useless in iOS Simulator mode and SwiftUI Canvas Preview mode.

```
// Use it only for compiled AR app, not simulated...

let _: AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment = .horizontal
```

Not only anchors are useless in `iOS Simulator Mode` and `SwiftUI Preview Mode` but also other **session-oriented properties** (including ARView.session) like ones you can see on a picture:

[image]

> 2. Change `.backgroundColor` in ARView to any other desirable one. Default color sometimes doesn't allow you to see a RealityKit scene. Looks like a bug.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
    boxAnchor.steelBox?.scale = SIMD3(5, 5, 5)
    boxAnchor.steelBox?.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: Float.pi/4, axis: SIMD3(1,1,0))

    arView.backgroundColor = .orange

    arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
    return arView
}
```

And here's what you can see in SwiftUI Preview Area now:

[image]

> 3. And, of course, you have to give a `Camera Permission` before using AR app. And it doesn't matter what you're using: Storyboard or SwiftUI.

You need to add **`Camera Usage Description`** property and **`arkit`** string in `info.plist` file:

[image]

XML version looks like this:

```
/*  info.plist


<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Camera access for AR experience</string>

<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
    <string>arkit</string>
</array>

*/
```

After fixing these issues app compiles and works as expected (without any errors):

[image]

Comment: Because I create the project by xCode and choose **Augmented Reality** App. So the Info.plist has already done.
After I created the project, it can build successful and can preview the SwiftUI canvas.
But if I use the **AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment** even use on the other file, the project still build successful, but it cannot preview the SwiftUI canvas.

Comment: I made this app using `Single View App` template for iOS (based on SwiftUI), then `added your code`, added some strings to `info.plist` file, added `.rcproject` file. And voila – it works. No errors.

Comment: Can you preview the SwiftUI canvas? Not build on the device. Just see the canvas on the xCode.

Comment: But you comment out "let _: AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment = .horizontal". If you use this code, then the SwiftUI cannot preview. @@

Comment: I wrote about it in section one: `You can't use anchoring component in Simulator or in SwiftUI Preview.....`

Comment: So I say you can create a new file, then import RealityKit and add the code ```let _: AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment = .horizontal```.
The preview cannot work too.

Comment: I use Xcode 11.2 in Catalina 10.15.1. What's your config? You see my project is working...

Comment: Same. Xcode 11.2 in Catalina 10.15.1. Did you add a new file and use the ```AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment```?

Comment: Nope. I used default files of SwiftUI template. And set target to iOS 13.2.

Comment: I only added `.rcproject` and configured `info.plist`.

Comment: Yes. You can try to add the new file. when the file use ```AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment```. Then the SwiftUI cannot preview.
confuse.

Comment: Added some `.swift` files and `.xib`. Still working and previewing. It seems Ok. `AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment` works only when I'm building AR app for iOS. It also seems Ok.

Comment: I still cannot preview. too strange. [This is my screenshot](https://imgur.com/bagXMiQ). If I remove the property, then it can preview.

Comment: You can't use this property while previewing, that's what I'm trying to tell you)))

Comment: Ok! Got it!  And I found the way to preview the canvas! Add ```#if !targetEnvironment(simulator) ... #endif```. Then it will can preview!!